# get props object from link react-router-native

Tags: react-native, react-router-native

How to do this? For example i find this:

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/dialog", state: { detail: message }}}>
text
</Link>
```

but if i want display **this.props.location.state**, then write **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters

```
Configure your route path to accept named parameters (:id):

<Route path='/route/:id' exact component={MyComponent} />
Then you can pass URL parameters such as IDs in your link to:

<Link to={`route/foo`}>My route</Link>
You can access the parameter within your component via the match object:

const {id} = props.match.params

console.log(id) // "foo"
```

Comment: `<Route
                  path="/dialog/:id"
                  component={() => <Dialog showMenuIcon={this.showMenuIcon} />}
                />`

Comment: and `<Link to={"/dialog/" + message}>`, message is object, but even string doesn't pass parametr.